# Can we save the answers for maven release:prepare for later use?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to dry-run before the real release happen. So I run with following command:

```
mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true
```

It asked a few questions like:

- There are still some remaining snapshot dependencies.: Do you want to resolve them now? (yes/no) no:
- Which release version should it be set to?
- What version should the dependency be reset to for development?

Is that possible to reuse answers for these questing, so I don't have to type them all over again when doing the real release?

I am aware the option `--batch`, but default values are not always correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use : release.properties
With :

```
scm.tag=my-proj-1.2
project.rel.org.myCompany\:projectA=1.2
project.dev.org.myCompany\:projectA=1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

See : http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html

Comment: Technically it is right, but when I first saw your answer, I got the impression that I have to manually edit the release.properties, that is not less convenient than passing them as command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for myself.

Steps:

1. `mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true`
2. remove the `completedPhase=end-release` from `release.properties` with

   ```
   sed -i -e 's/completedPhase=end-release//' release.properties
   ```
3. You can now run the real `release:perpare`

Note that before you do the real `release perpare`, no `release:clean` or `release:perform` should be run, even with `-DdryRun=true`